# I only got database output once, but not again. Why wont this work?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

I am working in firebase for a web app. The first time I did the query it worked, then I added the second reference and it broke. Upon doing that, I rolled back to when it previously worked and it no longer worked either. I am getting no errors in the console.

```
  function displayMessage(){
      var messageId;
      alert("Firebase Initializing UserID: " + Parse.User.current().id);
    var reference = new Firebase("https://gibber.firebaseio.com/Recent");
    reference.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(Parse.User.current().id).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        alert(snapshot.key());
        messageId = snapshot.key();
        });
    var reference2 = new Firebase("https://gibber.firebaseio.com/Recent");
    reference2.child(messageId+"/lastMessage").on("value", function(snapshot) {
      alert(snapshot.val());///snapshot should be last message
    });
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nesting of you code is off, which is hard to spot because the indentation is messy.

This works:

```
var userId = 'sKdkC6sGYb';
var ref = new Firebase("https://gibber.firebaseio.com/Recent");
ref.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userId).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log('child_added: '+snapshot.key());
    var messageId = snapshot.key();
    ref.child(messageId+"/lastMessage").on("value", function(othersnapshot) {
        console.log('value: '+othersnapshot.val());///snapshot should be last message
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why you're taking this two-queried approach though, the `lastMessage` property is available in the outer snapshot already:

```
var userId = 'sKdkC6sGYb';
var ref = new Firebase("https://gibber.firebaseio.com/Recent");
ref.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userId).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log('child_added: '+snapshot.key());
    console.log('value: '+snapshot.val().lastMessage);
});
```

See: http://jsbin.com/bikoni/edit?js,console

Comment: thanks! I am new to Firebase still and havent fully gotten the hang of the queries. That query looks a million times better. However, I put it in and I am still not getting output and it is not throwing and errors or warnings. I am looking at firebase and the items are definitely there. Again, the query worked the first time, but then broke when I tried to run it again.

Comment: Basically, I am just trying to look up the message with the appropriate user and then snapshot the message

Comment: I added a link to my jsbin. Have a look there, since it logs the last message with a single query.